# Spring Data Dependencies Error

Tags: java, dependencies, spring-data, dao

I have the folowing Error: "java: name clash:save in JpaRepository and save in CrudRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other."

I am using Intellij IDEA with dependencies:

Hibernate 5.2.9-5.2.9

Spring Data JPA-1.3.3

Spring-4.3.8.RELEASE

I am using:

```
@Repository
public interface PropietarioRepository extends JpaRepository<E, K>{}
```

as Data Access Layer.

Answer (score 0):

4.3.8-release is the latest stable version of Spring. 1.3.3 is a release from 2013, 4 years ago. Its pom indicates that it relies on spring 3.1.4.RELEASE.

Use a recent version of spring-data-jpa, that is compatible with Spring 4.3.8.

The latest stable version, compatible with spring 4.3.8, is 1.11.3: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework